# Raspberry pi shut down when used headless

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have made my raspberry pi run a certain program at boot up. There is no mouse or keyboard connected to the pi so how can I shut down the raspberry pi without keyboard or mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to shut down a Raspberry Pi without keyboard and mouse. Most require connection to Wi-Fi. Here are a few...

1. You can connect a button via the GPIO pins and add a program that waits for the button to be pressed and then issues a shutdown command.
2. You can enable SSH on the Raspberry Pi and log in remotely to issue a shutdown command. (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/)
3. You can sign up to VNC and enable it on your Raspberry Pi. This allows you to connect remotely to the desktop GUI and shut down normally. (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/)

Comment: Is the remote setup has to be done at first boot of Raspbian? If I have to  do the setup at first boot, I need to download a lot of libraries again which take like two days.

Comment: No. You can edit the setting from your Raspberry Pi desktop (but you will need keyboard+mouse+screen for setup) by finding `Raspberry Pi configuration` in the menu.

Comment: I've linked the documentation in my edited answer. This should help you to set something up. Good luck ;-)

Comment: I am doing face recognition project. Is ssh or vnc a better option? I will shut down the pi remotely and will copy files from my laptop to pi sometimes.

Comment: SSH would be a better option. You only need to issue the shutdown command and use [file transfer](https://www.simplified.guide/ssh/copy-file). You could also use [samba](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-samba/) for file transfer if you want (less hastle).

Comment: Thank you so much, pal. I will try.